# Getting error message trying to resize partition

Tags: partitioning, resize

Currently running Ubuntu 18.04 and i am trying to shrink its partition size and am receiving an error code im not sure what i should do.

```
error unmounting/dev/sda1:target is busy (udisks-error-quark,14)
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3):

The error implies the target device `/dev/sda1` is in some operation, hence the busy. I assume you're trying to resize partition within the running Ubuntu OS, it's obvious then—because partition can't be modified while they're in use.

To safely resize a 'running' partition, you must first unmount them, if the partition happen (I believe) to be the partition Ubuntu currently running at. Please run it from live system.

If you still have the bootable USB/CD that you used to install Ubuntu, you can get to live system from it. Otherwise, I suggest you to burn [Gparted Live System Image](https://gparted.org/livecd.php), which is dedicated image for gparted purpose only.